# Recreate image using only overlapping squares

Tags: algorithm, math, graphics

I'm trying to take a source image, and recreate it on a transparent canvas using only overlapping mono-colored squares. The goal is to use as few squares as possible.

In other words, I'm taking a blank transparent image, and drawing squares of various colors until I recreate the source image, with the goal being to use as few squares as possible.

For example:
[image: Sample image 1]
Here is a source image. It has two colors: red and green. I want to use **only squares**, that may overlap, to recreate the source image.

The ideal solution would be a large red square, and then two green squares drawn on top - that is what I want my algorithm to find, with any source image - the position, size, color and order of each square.

---

My target image that I intend to process is this:
[image: Target image]

(8x enlargement)

[image]

It has 1411 non-transparent pixels (worst case), and with a brute force solution that does not use overlapping squares, I've recreated the image using 1246 squares.

---

My current solution is a brute force method along the lines of:

1. Create a list of all colors used in the source image. Each item is a "layer". A layer has a color and a 2D array representing pixels. The order is important, but I don't know what order the layers need to be in, so its arbitrary initially.
2. For each layer in the list, initialize the 2D array. Each element corresponds to a pixel in the source image. Pixels that are the same color as the layer's chosen color is marked as '1'. Pixels that are in a layer ABOVE the current layer are marked as "don't care". All other pixels are marked as '0'.
3. Use some algorithm to process each layer, using the smallest number of squares to reach every pixel marked '1', without touching any pixels marked '0'.
4. Rearrange the order of layers and go back to Step 2. Do this for every possible combination of layers, then check to see which ordering uses the least number of squares in total.

Someone has perhaps a better explanation in a response; but brute force testing every permutation is not viable, because my target image has 31 colors (resulting in 31! permutations).

As for why I'm doing this? I'm trying to create an image in a game (Starbound), where I can only use squares. The lazy solution is to use a square for each pixel, but that's just too many squares.

Comment: You could get some ideas in the discussion of ["SMPAINT"](http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/33892/smpaint-editorial) challenge on CodeChef.

Comment: Sorry, the sample image I provided was not a very good one. I've updated the OP with some better images. To clarify, it's a red square with two green squares on a transparent background.

Comment: This is a relatively complex image and I doubt it will "compress" very well, because every corner will require it's own square, whatever you do.

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion for a possible solution. I haven't tried it.

It's a greedy approach.

For every pixel, compute the largest uniform square that contains it.

Then choose the largest of all squares and mark all pixels it covers as "covered".

Then among all unmarked pixels, choose the largest covering square, and so on until no unmarked pixel remains.

Ties do no matter, just take any largest square and mark its pixels.

UPDATE: overlaps offer opportunities for reduction in the number of squares.

Consider all possible permutations of the filling order of the shapes. The shapes drawn first, on the bottom layers, can be (partly) hidden by some others. Process the shapes starting from the top layer. When you process a shape to associate every pixel with the largest uniform square that contains it, treat all covered pixels as don't care.

In the given example, fill the green squares first; then when filling the red square, the green pixels can be considered red or not, depending on convenience.

If you cannot try all permutations, then try them at random. Heuristic approaches such as genetic algorithms or simulated annealing could help. Nothing straightforward here.

Comment: I've implemented this solution but it's not quite what I'm looking for; I'm hoping to reduce the number of squares needed by exploiting overlapping. This solution will not get the optimal answer of 3 squares in my example image.

Comment: That's right, the proposed approach does not take into account polygons with holes/occlusions. Suggestion for an approach: if a filling order can be decided (say green after red), then a shape will have hidden pixels, such that their color does not matter. This can be exploited for the operation "compute the largest uniform square". Can you afford to try all permutations of the filling order ?

Comment: I implemented a program to try all permutations, then I realized there were 31 colors (and thus 31! permutations) for the image I intend to process.

Comment: Actually you needn't try all permutations because there are shapes that do not overlap, so that their filling order may be indifferent. But this may not be sufficient to avoid the combinatorial explosion. Showing a true case would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It would be hard to guarantee an optimal solution.  The brute force search would be huge.  This calls for a heuristic.

Start at the edges.  Walking  the outside edge, find the most frequent color. Draw squares
to fill the background.

Iterate, working inwards drawing smaller and smaller squares which cover the most
pixels which are the wrong color.  Ending with single-pixel squares.

Working inwards means to reduce the size of the bounding box, outside
of which all pixels are the correct color.  At each step, the upper limit on the size of a square would be fitting in the bounding box.  Choose the squares which give the best score.

Score is based on old vs new color being wrong or right, so there are 4 possible values for each pixel.  One example function for per-pixel score would be:

- wrong -> wrong: 0
- wrong -> right: 1
- right -> right: 1
- right -> wrong: -2

I think that if you always reduce the number of wrong squares on the edge of the bounding box and never increase the size of the square, then the algorithm must halt with a solution without needing to backtrack.  A backtracking solution could probably do better.

Answer (score 0):

An "erosion-based" heuristic.

---

- Consider all outline pixels, i.e. having at least a neighbor outside the shape.
- Among these pixels, choose a color (the most frequent one ?).
- For all outline pixels of this color, compute the largest square that does not exceed the shape.
- Fill these squares, from larger to smaller, until the complete outline is covered.
- Remove the correctly filled pixels and restart the procedure on the eroded shape.

---

In the case of the red square, all outline pixels will be covered by the red square itself, and the first filling will "consume" the whole area.

Then, removing the pixels covered in red, the two green square will remain.

All green outline pixels will now be covered by the two green squares, and the two first fillings will "consume" all green area.

Comment: There is an essential difference: I recommend to process from the outline.

Comment: "having at least a neighbor outside the shape"

Comment: Yep. Anyway, considering the white pixels would reduce to the monster outline after the first iteration.